# Hangman vb.net only first letter showing

Tags: vb.net

Basically I generate a random word for example

"Tree" and when I press the T button it changes the label into a T but then when I choose R it doesnt show, can someone else see what i've done wrong?

here is my code

```
Sub GuessLetter(ByVal LetterGuess As String)
        Dim strGuessedSoFar As String = Lbltempword.Text
        Dim LengthOfSecretWord As Integer
        LengthOfSecretWord = secret.Length - 1
        tempWord = ""
        Dim letterPosition As Integer
        For letterPosition = 0 To LengthOfSecretWord

            If secret.Substring(letterPosition, 1) = LetterGuess Then
                tempWord = tempWord & LetterGuess
            Else
                tempWord = tempWord & Lbltempword.Text.Substring(letterPosition, 1)
            End If

        Next
        Lbltempword.Text = tempWord

        If Lbltempword.Text = secret Then 'YOU WIN
            DisableButtons()
            BtnStart.Enabled = True
            MsgBox("YOU WIN")
        End If

        If Lbltempword.Text = strGuessedSoFar Then
            NumWrong = NumWrong + 1
        End If


        DisplayHangman(NumWrong)
    End Sub



    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnStart.Click
        randomword()
        MsgBox(secret)
        EnableButtons()
        BtnStart.Enabled = False
        'Load up the temp word label with dashes
        Secret_Word = secret
        LoadLabelDisplay()
        NumWrong = 0
        DisplayHangman(NumWrong)
    End Sub


 Sub LoadLabelDisplay()
        Lbltempword.Text = ""
        Dim LengthOfSecretWord As Integer
        LengthOfSecretWord = secret.Length - 1
        Dim LetterPosition As Integer
        For LetterPosition = 0 To LengthOfSecretWord
            Lbltempword.Text = Lbltempword.Text & "-"
        Next
    End Sub
```

I also generate the random words by doing this.

```
Sub randomword()
        Dim RAND(16)
        Dim rng As New System.Random()
        For i = 0 To 16
            RAND(0) = "Tree"
            RAND(1) = "Star"
            RAND(2) = "Jesus"
            RAND(3) = "Present"
            RAND(4) = "advent"
            RAND(5) = "Calender"
            RAND(6) = "Jinglebell"
            RAND(7) = "skint"
            RAND(8) = "lapland"
            RAND(9) = "Santa"
            RAND(10) = "raindeer"
            RAND(11) = "Cookies"
            RAND(12) = "Milk"
            RAND(13) = "nothing"
            RAND(14) = "play"
            RAND(15) = "sack"
        Next
        secret = RAND(rng.Next(RAND.Count()))
    End Sub
```

Comment: My first thought is that you are actually trying to match "R" against "r", which are two different character codes. You probably should be using the .ToLower() function or .ToUpper() function on both `secret` and `LetterGuess`. For more information on string comparing in VB.Net, I suggest you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx

Comment: Argghhh How could I be so stupid. Thank you!

Comment: A couple of hints - you should change `LetterGuess As String` to `LetterGuess As Char` & you have miss-spelt "reindeer".

Comment: Also, the code `If Lbltempword.Text = strGuessedSoFar Then` just looks wrong to me. It's hard to follow your logic, but that just seems wrong.

Comment: It's fully working now. Yeah, I noticed I spelt it wrong :/ all good. Thanks guys